# Linked list destructor that loops forever?

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I'm working on making a linked list, and everything about it is working exactly as I want it to except for the list's destructor:

```
PhoneList::~PhoneList()
{
    PhoneNode *ptr = head;

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        head = head->getNext();
        delete ptr;
        ptr = head;
    }
}
```

When the program runs, it does everything else I need it to, but then seems to loop indefinitely on the destructor when it tries to call it and end the program. This is my first question here, and I'm a bit of a newcomer to this whole programming thing, so if you need to see any more of my program code to make sense of this destructor I will gladly share it!

Comment: It looks fine as it is, though slightly less confusing way IMO: `while (head) {PhoneNode* to_remove = head; head = head->getNext(); delete to_remove;}`. I think your bug is somewhere else besides the dtor with a malformed list. Double-check your insert and removal functions. Some people might be able to spot an issue if you post some of the code for those insert and removal functions. Most likely the infinite loop is caused by the list nodes not being linked properly.

Comment: I felt it should work too. And I also had the same thought, but taking this code out of the destructor and just leaving it blank completely resolved the issue. I feel like it has to be the destructor, as it calls and executes every other piece of code successfully until it hits the the end of the main(). I think the debugger has also just confirmed this suspicion, as when I break on the part of the program where it just sits, it tells me that the program is in the destructor's while loop.

Comment: also I appreciate the loop suggestion! love seeing ways to make my code a bit more clean :)

Comment: Leaving it blank might avoid the infinite loop traversing the list but the problem is most likely due to the list being malformed. Other list operations succeeding doesn't mean that they are leaving the list properly intact. For example, one of the next pointers might be pointing to garbage memory, at which point the loop in the destructor could end up looping infinitely. Try sharing some of the code for the insertion and removal of the list nodes -- I think we should be able to spot an issue in either of those.

Comment: In all the constructors of PhoneNode, do you set `next` to null?

Comment: yes, every PhoneNode constructor initializes next to null.

Comment: Ugh, nothing jumps out to me immediately. In terms of simplifications though, you can simplify a lot using a pointer to a pointer: https://paste.ofcode.org/a9GQC5tLjguikvygs7sphw. How about posting the entire code? It's not so huge, is it?

Comment: sure, I can post the entire code for you!

Comment: The copy constructor to me is a little bit suspect. That could be tricky in a linked list as copying a node will lead to a node which has a different address, while the original could end up being destroyed.

Comment: You are totally right, it is a bit suspect. But I actually don't ever use it, and meant to delete it from the program as well. I'll remove it from my post, sorry about that.

Comment: I see the code now -- but do you have a test program for the list: a `main.cpp` sort of thing? Mainly I wanna reproduce the same issue with same test condition.

Comment: You silly goose!!! :-D The destructor in your full program has a semicolon: `while (ptr != NULL);` That's going to cause an infinite loop if the list is non-empty. You didn't include the semicolon in your original snippet (which is fine).

Comment: oh. my. god. I... cannot BELIEVE I didn't see that. Wow. Well that's a bit embarrassing. Thank you so much for pointing that out. Now I go hang my head in shame for the next 3 hours

Comment: `while (ptr != NULL);` with the semicolon there is equivalent to `while (ptr != NULL) {/* do nothing*/}` which will cause an infinite loop if `ptr` is not null to begin with. Your full source code has that bug in it but funnily your original snippet was fine.

Comment: Don't worry about it! But I'm just kind of confused because your original snippet was already fixed. :-D I recommend learning how to use whatever debugger comes with your compiler/IDE though. That can save you hours.

Comment: That's also how I found your issue so quickly after you posted the full code. I wrote a quick test against it, ran it through the debugger, saw the infinite loop in the destructor, and spotted the semicolon as a result of tracing through it. My eyes aren't that good (I'm old) so I wouldn't have spotted it either, but the debugger misses nothing. So the debugger is a lifesaver.

Comment: yeah I was actually having trouble copy-pasting the code before I figured out what the ctrl+k command did, so I just wrote it in there and I guess subconsciously just threw out the semicolon. not sure why i even put it in there in the first place, must've just not been paying any attention at all..

Comment: Funnily you ended up fixing the issue through a copy/paste manuscript error. :-D Another thing that can be a lifesaver is to enable all the warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. A good one might be able to detect that you have a potential infinite loop there and alert you about it.

Comment: xD tell me about it.. and I will do! anything to help me avoid that trainwreck of an error again.. I very much appreciate all the help and advice though, Team Upvote! :D

Comment: Cheers! Also I ended up giving the code a look over and did some things to simplify it, specifically with respect to the list traversal functions in PhoneList. Check it out: https://paste.ofcode.org/PMSt2tK9nzhmWu4u9dxp2w. In particular you can avoid keeping track of the previous node on removals from the middle of the list by using a pointer *to* a pointer to a node. That might seem a bit confusing at first but once you grasp it, everything will seem so much easier and less error-prone.

Comment: Another thing is this type of code: `if (expression) return true; else return false;` can simply be written as `return expression;`... which again might seem less intuitive at first, but once you get the hang of how expressions evaluate, it'll cut down the amount of code you have to read/write by quite a bit, and it'll be easier to skim over things and understand what they do very quickly.

Comment: Here's a quick diagram to illustrate how pointers to pointers work with respect to linked list removal. https://pasteboard.co/H7fD3CI.png. If you can take some time to comprehend this and understand the code I pasted, it'll set you apart from the average linked list implementer, and set you in Linus Torvalds' eyes as a programmer of "good taste". :-D

Comment: woah, that's pretty neat! I had no idea that was even a thing :o I'll be staring at this code trying to figure out what's happening for the next couple hours, probably. and that's not a bad thing, I love trying to figure out code I'm not entirely familiar with on my own! best way to learn, imho. can't overstate how much I appreciate all of this :D

Comment: Generally it's not so much of a thing in C++ since most people don't bother to implement linked lists and just use `std::list` or `std::vector`, e.g. In C it's rather common to implement linked lists by hand though, and it's usually done in production in a way where each linked list node is pooled from a contiguous pool of memory to mitigate the cache misses on traversal. That's getting a bit advanced but there's a lot of good use for linked lists that's sometimes overlooked in C++, but they're not so efficient by default because of the way they tend to disperse memory all over the place.

Comment: A little particle sim using linked lists I wrote w/ 4 million particles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQNnb.gif -- maybe something to wet your appetite a bit while you learn about them.  They're actually stored in a grid with each cell being a list node along with each particle, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXgX5.png. Oh well, this stuff should be baby stuff to you after a while! Best of luck!

Comment: WOW! that is SO cool.. wetting my appetite might be a bit of an understatement. this is the kind of stuff that keeps me going!

Answer (score -2):

You would be better off adding a destructor for `PhoneNode`, such that each each deletes its successor. Then you don't need the loop at all:

```
PhoneNode::~PhoneNode()
{
    delete next;
}
```

Note that this traverses the entire remaining list.

then your `PhoneList` destructor just looks like:

```
PhoneList::~PhoneList()
{
    delete head;
}
```

Take care in your `Delete(int id)` method that you zero the `next` pointer of a node you're going to delete if it's in the middle of the list (i.e. it isn't already zero). Otherwise you lose the entire rest of the list.

Comment: good point! hadn't looked at it that way. but I am still generally curious as to why it doesn't work, as I've rattled my brain trying to trace through the code and everything *seems* to work just fine. And pardon my ignorance, but I'm not quite seeing how zeroing the 'next' pointer of a node in the middle of my list before deleting it will do anything differently... doesn't my code delete a node and set the 'next' of the previous node equal to the 'next' of the deleted node? essentially skipping over it and then freeing the memory?

Comment: in fact, wouldn't zeroing the 'next' of the pointer im going to delete actually cause the dropping of everything after it because I'm setting the 'next' of the previous node equal to whatever the deleted node's 'next' was pointing to? and then the previous node would point to null, forgetting everything that came after the deleted node? im just genuinely curious, because I thought I had that working perfectly

Comment: You have to be careful using a recursive destructor like this. If the list is large, you can cause a stack overflow error, because every destructor call pushes a parameter (the `this` pointer) onto the call stack. Using an iterative loop is safer.

Comment: @phillyb You have to (a) save `next`(b) set `next = NULL;` (c) process the saved value of `next`.